# Extraer campos específicos de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

Tengo una interfaz como esta:

```
const hortalizas{
tomates,
patatas,
cebollas
}
```

Un array que contiene:

```
[
{
lechugas: {cantidad: 3, envases: 'bolsa' }, 
tomates: {cantidad: 1, envases: 'bolsa' },
zanahorias: {cantidad: 2, envases: 'cesta' },
cebollas: {{cantidad: 3, envases: 'bolsa' }, 
}, 
{
lechugas: {cantidad: 8, envases: 'bolsa' }, 
tomates: {cantidad: 1, envases: 'bolsa' },
zanahorias: {cantidad: 4, envases: 'cesta' },
cebollas: {{cantidad: 3, envases: 'bolsa' },
}
]
```

Con esto:

```
const hortalizas = verduras.map((verdura) => verdura.hortaliza)
```

me devuelve un objeto como este:

```
const hortalizas: {
[key: string]: {
cantidad: number;
envases: string;
};
}[]
```

¿Cómo puedo extraer, a partir de ese .map, un array con solo los objetos que coinciden con la interfaz llamada "hortalizas"?

Algo como esto:

```
[
{
tomates: {cantidad: 1, envases: 'bolsa'},
cebollas: {cantidad: 3, envases: 'bolsa'}
{
tomates: {cantidad: 1, envases: 'bolsa'},
cebollas: {cantidad: 3, envases: 'bolsa'},
}
]
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Sabes el nombre todos los campos que vendrán en el objeto?

Comment: Los que coincidan con los de la interfaz son los que debería devolver

Answer (score 0):

Espero haber entendido bien tu pregunta, en este caso puedes recorrer el array con un forEach y filtrar solo los elementos que deseas en la salida:

```
let output = [];
let object;
array.forEach(e => {
    let object = new Object({
        tomates: e.tomates,
        cebollas: e.cebollas
    });
    output.push(object);
})
```

Para filtrarlo creas un nuevo objeto, le asignas sus elementos y mediante el elemento **'e'** y lo agregas al array de salida.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El problema es que este ejemplo es reducido. El objeto que recibo tiene muchos más campos y también son más los que debo filtrar, de ahí que crease una interfaz para definirlos.